# angular mat-select can't show icon of select Item

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to use angular select material, I need to add the icon dynamically to options and show it when selected
my ts code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select disableOptionCentering panelClass="dropDown-panel" (selectionChange)="onRoomChange($event.value)">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let type of roomTypes" [value]="type.roomTypeId">
                {{ type.faName }}
           <mat-icon>{{ type.icon }}</mat-icon>
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

this code add icon to options list but when select one of them ,show icon name instead of icon
[image]

**home is select value and house is icon name but need to show something like this**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `mat-select-trigger`. documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger)

on `onRoomChange` set `selectedtype`.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select disableOptionCentering panelClass="dropDown-panel" (selectionChange)="onRoomChange($event.value)">
    <mat-select-trigger>
          <span>{{selectedtype.faName}}</span>
          <mat-icon>{{selectedtype.icon}}</mat-icon>
        </mat-select-trigger>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let type of roomTypes" [value]="type.roomTypeId">
                {{ type.faName }}
           <mat-icon>{{ type.icon }}</mat-icon>
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[working example](https://angular-pu29yl.stackblitz.io)

Comment: could you please complete your answer by ts file

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use "mat-select-trigger" option, as shown here, [MatSelectTrigger](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger)

Also I have created demo to achieve this, please refer the same :
stackblitz URL : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wzqo1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use **mat-select-trigger**, refer [Mat-Select-trigger](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger)

```
<mat-form-field style="width:200px;">
  <mat-select name="countryVaraible" [(value)]="selectedCountry" placeholder="Country" (selectionChange)="onRoomChange($event)">
   <mat-select-trigger>
     <span *ngIf="selectedValue" >
  {{selectedValue.full}}
 <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">{{selectedValue.icon}}</mat-icon>
  </span>
</mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
      {{country.full}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

find complete demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-ex3qcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)